# save multiple data through select box using laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I've been trying to figure out how to submit multiple values through a select box using laravel4.i have no idea how to write code in my controller file.

I've made several attempts to achieve this but have yet to work out how to do it.
code that i have written for in my view
Workers available to check in

```
{{ Form::select('name[]', $worker_list , '', array('class' => 'input-medium field', 'multiple' => 'multiple'))  }}
```

This is my controller action:

```
public function postCreate(){
    $name = Input::get('name');
    $search_data = array('name' => $name);
    return Redirect::to('events')->with($search_data);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your controller ?

Comment: public function postCreate()
  {
 $name = Input::get('name');
   $search_data = array(
        'name'         => $name,
        return Redirect::to('events')->with($search_data);
       
    );
    

    
        }

Comment: @maghna I added your code to the question. (You can do that yourself by clicking **edit**) I correct a mistake while doing. The `return` was inside the array. I'm assuming this was only from pasting in the comments and your original code looks the one I added to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you expect, but when you call Input::get('name') you should get an array of the values you have selected.

```
return Redirect::to('events')->withName(Input::get('name'));
```

This might be what you want to achive?

Otherwise, is the content of the variable $workerlist what you expect when you parse it into the select?

Comment: actually i need to post all the content of the variable $worklist to database once we click save button..thnx

Comment: Okey, so not just the selected ones? Then why use a select? I would probably just send it through without a selectlist in that case, like a hidden field or something.